# Бексонечный цикл программы

Tags: java

```
    public class Main 
    {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    char[] cons = {'б','в','г','д','ж','й','з','к','л','м','н','п','р','с','т','ф','ч','х','ц','ш','щ','Б','В','Г','Д','Ж','Й','З','К','Л','М','Н','П','Р','С','Т','Ф','Ч','Х','Ц','Ш','Щ'};    
    char[] sings = {'!','?',':',';','.',','};      
    int sovp = 0;
    int sign1 = 0;
    String task = "Заменить! в тексте все слова! длиной, не больше 6 символов. в обратном порядке: начинающиеся на; согласную букву.";
    System.out.println(task);
    String[] strArr = task.split(" ");// деление текста на отдельные слова   
    
    for (int i=0;i<strArr.length;i++)
    { 
      char first = strArr[i].charAt(0);//первая буква       
      int signpos = strArr[i].length()-1;
      char sign = strArr[i].charAt(signpos);//последний знак          
      
      for (int isings = 0; isings < 6; i++)// проверка на наличие знаков препинания в конце слова
        {
            if (sign == sings[isings])
            {
                sign1 = 1;
            }               
        }
      
      for (int a= 0; a < 42; a++)//проверка первой буквы
      {
        if (first == cons[a])
        {
          sovp = 1;
        }           
      }
      
      if ((strArr[i].length()-1 <= 6) && (sovp==1))//проверка длины и наличие согласной первой буквы
      {       
        if (sign1 == 1)//есть знак препинания в конце
        {               
            StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer(strArr[i]);
            sBuffer.deleteCharAt(signpos);
            sBuffer.reverse();
            sBuffer.append(sign);
            System.out.print(sBuffer + " ");
            sign1 = 0;
        }
        
        else 
        {           
            StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer(strArr[i]);
            sBuffer.reverse();
            System.out.print(sBuffer + " ");            
        }   
        sovp = 0;
      }     
      
      else System.out.print(strArr[i] + ' ');         
     }      
}
```

}

Comment: Компилятор никаких ошибок не выдает, однако до конца не выполняется

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка кроется здесь:

```java
for (int isings = 0; isings < 6; i++)// проверка на наличие знаков препинания в конце слова
```

Вы объявлете переменную-счётчик под названием `isings`, но при этом увеличиваете `i`, из-за чего первая переменная не изменяется, делая цикл бесконечным.